# Why I cannot get translated entities

Tags: 8, entities, i18n-l10n

I wrote service to get all necessary data for my page. Now I wanted to load them with translations. But whey I try, I got error:

> InvalidArgumentException: Invalid translation language (id of language here) specified.

When I open page in default language it works fine. Does it mean that I need to translate all of the things in order to make it work?

My service:

```
namespace service;
use Drupal\Core\Language\LanguageInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Url;
use entity\Entity;

class PostTypeService
{
    public static function getEntititiesByPostType($postType, $entities = array(), $nid = NULL)
    {

        if ($nid != NULL) {
            $nids = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
                ->condition('type', $postType)
                ->condition('status', 1)
                ->condition('nid', $nid)
                ->execute();
        } else {
            $nids = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
                ->condition('type', $postType)
                ->condition('status', 1)
                ->execute();

        }

        $nodes = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::loadMultiple($nids);
        $returnValues = array();
        $language = \Drupal::languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage()->getId();
        foreach ($nodes as $index => $node) {
            foreach ($entities as $entity) {
                $type = $entity->type;
                $entity_name = $entity->entity;
                if ($type == 'image') {
                    $returnValues[$postType][$index][$entity->entity] = file_create_url($node->$entity_name->entity->getFileUri());
                } else if ($type == 'url') {
                    $returnValues[$postType][$index][$entity->entity . '_uri'] = $node->$entity_name->uri;
                    $returnValues[$postType][$index][$entity->entity . '_title'] = $node->$entity_name->title;
                } else if ($type == 'list') {
                    foreach ($node->$entity_name as $list_item) {
                        $returnValues[$postType][$index][$entity->entity][] = $list_item->value;
                    }
                } else {
                    $translation = $node->getTranslation($language);
                    $returnValues[$postType][$index][$entity->entity] = $translation->$entity_name->$type;
                }
            }
            $returnValues[$postType][$index]['node_id'] = $index;
            $options = array('absolute' => TRUE);
            $url = Url::fromRoute('entity.node.canonical', ['node' => $index], $options)->toString();
            $returnValues[$postType][$index]['node_url'] = $url;
            $returnValues[$postType][$index]['lang'] = $language;
        }
        return $returnValues;
    }
```

Comment: I just checked and I was right. The problem is that not all of the content is translated

Comment: Enable error log with verbose information, check the backtrace. Core should always fall back, you might have custom or contrib code that forces the current language and doesn't check if it exists.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I fixed it with this code:

   if (!array_key_exists($language, $node->getTranslationLanguages())) {
                $translation = $node->getTranslation($defaultLang);
            } else {
                $translation = $node->getTranslation($language);
            }

Comment: You should add your own answer.

Comment: You can use hasTranslation(), but actually, you probably want to use getTranslationFromContext. https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Entity!EntityRepositoryInterface.php/function/EntityRepositoryInterface%3A%3AgetTranslationFromContext/8.2.x

Answer (score -1):

This solves the problem:

```
namespace service;

use Drupal\Core\Language\LanguageInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Url;
use entity\Entity;

class PostTypeService
{
    public static function getEntititiesByPostType($postType, $entities = array(), $nid = NULL)
    {



        if ($nid != NULL) {
            $nids = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
                ->condition('type', $postType)
                ->condition('status', 1)
                ->condition('nid', $nid)
                ->execute();
        } else {
            $nids = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
                ->condition('type', $postType)
                ->condition('status', 1)
                ->execute();

        }

        $nodes = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::loadMultiple($nids);


        $language = \Drupal::languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage()->getId();
        $defaultLang = \Drupal::languageManager()->getDefaultLanguage()->getId();

        $returnValues = array();
        foreach ($nodes as $index => $node) {

            if (!array_key_exists($language, $node->getTranslationLanguages())) {
                $translation = $node->getTranslation($defaultLang);
            } else {
                $translation = $node->getTranslation($language);
            }

            foreach ($entities as $entity) {
                $type = $entity->type;
                $entity_name = $entity->entity;
                if ($type == 'image') {
                    $returnValues[$postType][$index][$entity->entity] = file_create_url($translation->$entity_name->entity->getFileUri());
                } else if ($type == 'url') {
                    $returnValues[$postType][$index][$entity->entity . '_uri'] = $translation->$entity_name->uri;
                    $returnValues[$postType][$index][$entity->entity . '_title'] = $translation->$entity_name->title;
                } else if ($type == 'list') {
                    foreach ($translation->$entity_name as $list_item) {
                        $returnValues[$postType][$index][$entity->entity][] = $list_item->value;
                    }
                } else {
                    $returnValues[$postType][$index][$entity->entity] = $translation->$entity_name->$type;
                }
            }
            $returnValues[$postType][$index]['node_id'] = $index;
            $options = array('absolute' => TRUE);
            $url = Url::fromRoute('entity.node.canonical', ['node' => $index], $options)->toString();
            $returnValues[$postType][$index]['node_url'] = $url;
            $returnValues[$postType][$index]['lang'] = $language;
        }
        return $returnValues;
    }
}
```